# Unable to upload new build on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, osx-yosemite, itunes-store, xcode-6.2

I have already gone through various similar questions asked here on Stack Overflow and also on other blogs. Unfortunately, none of those solutions are resolving my issue.

After doing a lot of search & when I was not able to solve my issue, I decided to ask you all.

I will explain scenario briefly. I have already uploaded iOS application for beta testing on iTunes Connect. My app's current status in iTunes Connect is "Expired" as 30 days testing period is over. I did few source code modifications and I want to make this updated application available for testers. Therefore, I tried to upload new build version for the app.

What I did is -

1. **App version** (Bundle versions string.short) - **Not modified (1.0)**
2. **Bundle version** - Modified from **"1.1"** to **"1.1.1"**
3. **Build** the application
4. Submitted application - **Window -> Organizer -> Submit**

Even though I did it properly, I am getting error as in below -

[image: Redundant Binary Error]

Can anyone of you please help me to understand where I might be doing mistake? Any help is appreciated.

Edit 1:

I tried to use build version 1.2/ 1.2.1 as well. Also I tried to upload a complete new app record in iTunes Connect with app version 2.0 and build version 2.1.0/ 210, but everytime got same error.

Edit 2:

My app's current status in iTunes Connect is **"Expired"**. Will it matter while uploading new build version for same app? If yes, what could be the best solution for such issue?

Comment: instead of 1.1.1 try to have 1.2 as a bundle version.

Comment: Yes try 1.2 as a bundle version.

Comment: I tried that as well and still was getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my issue got resolved. Along with modifying the Build version and keeping the Bundle version as it is, we need to check for few **build settings** whether they are set properly.

I was missing them and that is why I was not able to upload updated version of my application to iTunes Connect.

Please, refer below screen shot for these **Build Setting**.

[image: Required build settings]

You can find complete blog here - [iOS 8 Beta testing with TestFlight](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224)

This helped me and I hope this will help few others.